# Next.js middleware get available locales

Tags: next.js

i created i18n.json

**i18n.json**

```
{
  "locales": ["en-US", "tr-TR"],
  "defaultLocale": "tr-TR",
  "defaultNS": "common",
  "pages": {
    "*": ["common"]
  }
}
```

i want to get locales ["en-US", "tr-TR"] values in _middleware.tsx

i created _middleware.tsx and
I have read the directions in this document
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/server#nextrequest
**nextUrl includes i18n**
so i want to reach locales in i18n object but I get undefined value.

```
 import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";
    
 export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {

   const { i18n } = req.nextUrl;
   const { locales } = i18n;

   console.log(locales);

   return NextResponse.next();
 }
```

How can I get the available locales values?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you need middleware for this case, you can get all locales from the SSR props, but you need to configure

**First, you need to define your locales in next-18next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: "de",
    locales: ["de", "en"],
  },
};
```

**Then in next page get all locales with SSR Props**

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ locales }) => {
   console.log(locales) // You should get an array of all locales
}
```

Comment: Since Next.js supports locale detection only for root path ("/"), I use this to detect locales for all paths. This way, i am able to do redirects if required.

Answer (score 0):

For now, best way to do this is importing `next-i18next.config.js` manually.

**next-i18next.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: "en",
    locales: ["en", "tr"],
    localeDetection: false,
  },
};
```

**middleware.js**

```js
import { i18n } from "./next-i18next.config.js";

export function middleware(req) {
   const availableLocales = i18n.locales;
}
```

You can import your `i18n.json` to achieve same.